# « Ce témoin, appelé Marine, raconte » ou « Ce témoin, appelée Marine, raconte » ?

Tags: grammaire, genre, accord, genre-biologique

Comment accorde-t-on un adjectif se référant à un nom commun masculin, si ce nom commun représente une femme ?

A priori, j'aurais tendance à accorder l'adjectif avec le genre du sujet désigné, en l'occurrence *Marine*.

Merci d'éclairer ma lanterne !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux options sont, d'après moi, valides.

- Si vous voulez coller à la lettre de la règle grammaticale, vous écrivez : *« Ce témoin, appelé Marine, raconte »*.
- Si vous voulez coller à l'esprit de la règle grammaticale, vous écrivez : *« Ce témoin, appelée Marine, raconte »*. Cela s'appelle une [syllepse de genre <sup>wiki</sup>](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse#Syllepse_selon_le_genre).

Comment: Le mieux étant sûrement d'éviter les deux. « Marine, qui était témoin, raconte… »

Comment: Rapide, clair et efficace, que demande le peuple? Merci!