Accord nom de métier masculin pour une femme
Je suis romancière, et rencontre un dilemme d'accord avec mes personnages féminins occupant des postes historiquement masculins.
Je vais prendre comme exemple: chef (de projet, de bataillon, etc.).
Je choisis de conserver le nom au masculin (le chef = la tête) pour ces femmes. Merci de ne pas me suggérer les néologismes qui ne sont pas une option.
Quel accord choisir pour le reste de la phrase? 6 adjectifs masculins pour une femme pourraient faire douter le lecteur, donc idéalement j'aimerais écrire:

Le chef s'avança, fière et sereine, mais ressentant un doute au fond
d'elle-même.

Apparemment cela s'appelle la syllepse de genre. Est-ce grammaticalement correct?
Ou alors, puisque j'ai fait le choix du substantif masculin, est-il obligatoire d'écrire:

Le chef s'avança, fier et serein, mais ressentant un doute au fond de
lui-même.

Pour une femme?
Y a-t-il une règle commune à tous les noms dans ce contexte (le deuxième sur ma liste étant "juge"), ou des exceptions?
N'ayant pas trouvé de source sur les accords après n'avoir trouvé que des articles de l'Académie française sur les noms, mis à part cette discussion externe, je suis curieuse de voir les vôtres. Par exemple des exemples d'auteurs jusqu'au XXe siècle avec cette syllepse de genre.

https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2259/1109

Voir en particulier ce commentaire:  4 Le mieux étant sûrement d'éviter les deux. « Marine, qui était témoin, raconte… » –  Stéphane Gimenez  Mar 22, 2012 at 14:03

@jlliagre Je ne suis pas d'accord. Pas besoin d'éviter quoi que ce soit.

What is wrong with 'la cheffe'?

Cheffe de cabinet : Mme Vanina Nicoli. — (Arrêté du 3 juillet 2012 portant nomination au cabinet de la ministre de l’Égalité des territoires et du logement sur Légifrance)

@Dimitris I think the author chooses to use chef as in chef-lieu, le chef = la tête.

@Frank le chef-lieu, la chef-ville !


Est-ce grammaticalement correct ?

On demande ici l'avis d'une grammaire prescriptive puisque qu'on parle de « correct ». La réponse est alors forcément « non ». La prescription demande que les adjectifs s'accordent en genre et en nombre avec les noms qu'ils qualifient et chef est ici utilisé au masculin. Par définition, une syllepse ne respecte pas les règles de la grammaire.
On s'interdit aussi d'utiliser des néologismes sans les nommer, j'imagine qu'on pense à cheffe (voire cheffesse ou cheftaine ?) mais ce n'est pas nécessaire. Comme déjà justement évoqué dans la réponse de @ninja米étoilé, il suffit de changer l'article pour obtenir une phrase cohérente que nul correcteur n'amendera.

La chef s'avança, fière et sereine, mais ressentant un doute au fond d'elle-même.

Il en va bien sûr de même pour la juge, l'auteur, la médecin-chef, la chef de projet, etc.
On peut observer que chef est attesté au féminin depuis plus de 400 ans. On trouve par exemple la chef ville du païs de Flandre en 1571 (Chroniques et Annales de Flandre), aussi plus tard la chef-confrérie (Messager des sciences historiques, 1877).


Mettre tout au masculin est l'autre option respectueuse de la grammaire mais c'est un choix qu'on ne rencontre plus souvent :

Le chef s'avança, fier et serein, mais ressentant un doute au fond de lui-même.

La grammaire de cette phrase n'est pourtant pas fondamentalement différente de celle de la suivante qui ne pose aucun problème même quand elle décrit un homme :

La victime innocente est morte à 11 heures.


Très bonne analyse. Dans le cas de "chef", il s'agit à la base d'un substantif masculin, et je voyais l'article féminin pour éviter la syllepse comme commettre une "incorrection" pour en éviter une autre.

Dans la chef ville, chef est un adjectif qualificatif, l'article la se rapporte à ville, chef ne fait que qualifier le nom ville pour indiquer que c'est un type particulier de ville.

@Frank On peut le voir comme un adjectif mais c'est un détail qui ne contredit pas que chef pouvait déjà être épicène.

@jlliagre Si chef est le nom du groupe la chef ville, quelle est la fonction de ville?

@Frank Chef-lieu et chef-ville sont je pense pour les grammaires modernes des substantifs composés de deux noms juxtaposés mais chef a bien valeur d'adjectif puisqu'il qualifie la ville comme tu l'as écrit plus haut. En toute logique, il devrait, comme probablement tous les adjectifs en -f, prendre la terminaison -ve au féminin mais on ne peut que constater que "*chève" est inconnu.

Ça ressemble à la question que j'ai posée hier, qui tourne autour de la syllepse, comme tu le dis. Accorder suivant le sens plutôt que la grammaire a une longue histoire, et il y a de nombreux exemples sur la wikipedia à "syllepse". Un exemple tout simple:

Elle avait l’air soucieux/se

On peut utiliser les deux, soit pour respecter la grammaire et accorder soucieux avec air, soit pour mettre l'accent sur l'expérience du sujet.
De toute façon, en tant qu'auteur, tu peux choisir l'accord qui te convient - la langue évolue constamment, et l'Académie ne fait que suivre ce qu'utilisent les auteurs. J'aime bien mon on étaient tous copains qui est archi-faux grammaticalement. Il n'y a pas de difficulté de compréhension, ce qui est le plus important, et si ça fait réfléchir le lecteur, tant mieux.

Pour moi il y avait une différence. J'ai fait la syllepse "abstraite" sans réfléchir depuis des années. Mais lorsqu'on parle de personnes, dont le genre (dans un livre qu'on tente de suivre) est autrement plus important que celui d'un nom commun dans le dictionnaire, je n'avais pas compris qu'autorisation pour l'une valait pour l'autre. Dans mon cas je n'essaie pas de faire réfléchir par une langue (traditionnellement) incorrecte (qui génèrerait des pauses frustrées dans mon giga-pavé), mais plutôt les figures de style et surtout le fond des intrigues, d'où mes choix.

@Ety Note que je n'ai pas dit qu'il n'y avait pas de différence. Je dis juste qu'en tant qu'auteur, tu es libre de choisir la tournure que tu préfères, et même de faire une fôte si tu as envie.
